# Display and parse sensor data (text) in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

i'm new to flex. I have a sensor that sends data as text file. Data format as follow: dat=110405120000+000.00+000.00+005.65+000.00+040.71+000.00+000.00+000.20.

How can i parse this data? The output i want is:

date: 05-04-11
time: 12:00:00
ch01: 000.00
ch02: 000.00
ch03: 005.65
ch04: 000.00
ch05: 040.71
ch06: 000.00
ch07: 000.00
ch08: 000.20

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function:

```
private function parse_data(input:String):Array {
  input = input.replace("\x20",""); 
  input = input.replace("dat=","");
  var numbers:Array = input.split("+");

  //get date
  var year:String = String(numbers[0]).substr(0,2);
  var month:String = String(numbers[0]).substr(2,2);
  var day:String = String(numbers[0]).substr(4,2);
  var date:String = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;

  //get time
  var hours:String = String(numbers[0]).substr(6,2);
  var mins:String = String(numbers[0]).substr(8,2);
  var secs:String = String(numbers[0]).substr(10,2);
  var time:String = hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;

  //output array
  var output:Array = new Array();
  output["date"] = date;
  output["time"] = time;

  //other chxx values
  for (var index:int=1; index<numbers.length; index++) {
    output["ch0"+index] = numbers[index];
  }

  return output;
}
```

this is how to call the function above:

```
var result:Array = 
parse_data("dat=110405120000+000.00+000.00+005.65+000.00+040.71+000.00+000.00+000.20");
```

this is the array result:

```
{
  date:"05-04-11", 
  time:"12:00:00", 
  ch01:"000.00", 
  ch02:"000.00", 
  ch03:"005.65", 
  ch04:"000.00", 
  ch05:"040.71",
  ch06:"000.00",
  ch07:"000.00",
  ch08:"000.20"
}
```

to access this array:

```
var date:String = result["date"];
var time:String = result["time"];
var ch01:String = result["ch01"];
...
```

however ch01 above is a string, if you need integer value, you have to convert:

```
var ch01_value:int = int(ch01);
```

hope this may help

P.S.:
BIG NOTE: the above function works well only if you have 'ch01' to 'ch09',
if you have 'ch10' or more, you will need to amend it.

Comment: What does input = input.replace("\x20",""); do?

Comment: just in case the input string has unnecessary space characters, i always have extra caution for everything, haha

Comment: I get ya, only ever used replace(" ",""); myself. Checked it out using as3term, good to know

Comment: yeah, i often use "\x20" and avoid using " " because i'm afraid that some other guy in my team may change the code by adding one more space inside the " ", and if so, everything crashes down

Comment: There's something i wanna ask:at first, i use this code (to get variable dat), wonder where went wrong with the array: 'var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(loader.data);
     trace(variables.dat);
     var datatest:Array= variables.dat.split("+");
     var showdata:String= "Windspeed=" + datatest[3];'
 Did it right that i expect the datatest array as { "110405120000","000.00","000.00","005.65",etc}? But when i write showdata, it didn't show any result.

Answer (score 0):

read the file: http://www.openwritings.net/content/read-text-whole-file
use String.split() and other String functions: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html
You can always add regular expressions to the formula too (RegExp) :]

blz